# React and D3 Alignment Histogram

Tags: javascript, react.js, d3.js

I'm reasonably new to `D3`, and I've put together a class based `React` component which outputs a genomic alignment visually. The result looks like this:

[image]

The component is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

const StyledSVG = styled.svg`

  rect {
    fill: steelblue;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }

  text {
    fill: black;
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    text-anchor: middle;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .start, .note {
    text-anchor: start;
  }


`

let height = 150;
let width = 700;
const maxDepthVal = 35;

class Alignment extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    if(props.height){
      height = props.height;
    }

    if(props.width){
      width = props.width;
    }
  }

  findMax = (data, key) => {
    return Math.max.apply(Math, data.map(o => o[key]))
  }

  renderAlignmentComponent = (arr, y, ref, barWidth, leftPadding) => {

    d3.select(ref).selectAll('text')
    .data(arr, d => d.key)
      .join(
        enter => enter.append('text')
            .attr('transform', (d, i) => `translate(${leftPadding + (i * (barWidth)) }, 0)`)
            .attr('x', (d, i) => barWidth/2)
            .attr('y', y)
            .text(d => d.base),
        update => update
            .attr('transform', (d, i) => `translate(${leftPadding + i * barWidth}, 0)`)
            .attr('x', (d, i) => barWidth/2)

      )

  }

  renderMarker = (data, ref, y ) => {

    d3.select(ref).selectAll('text').data(data)
      .join('text')
        .attr('x', 10)
        .attr('y', y)
        .attr('class', 'start')
        .attr('dy', '.75em')
        .text(d => d)
  }

  renderLabel = (data, ref, y) => {

    d3.select(ref)
    .selectAll('text')
     .data(data)
    .join(
      enter => enter.append('text')
        .attr('x', 10)
        .attr('y', y)
        .attr('class', 'note')
        .attr('dy', '.75em')
        .text(d => d),
      update => update,
      exit => exit.remove()
    )

  }


  componentDidUpdate = () => {

    const { reference, alignment, depth, start } = this.props;

    const leftPadding = 40 + start.toString().length * 4.5;
    const topPadding = reference.length > 0 ? 38 : 0;
    const barWidth = (width - leftPadding) / depth.length;

    let i;

    const chart = d3.select(this.refs.chart)
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height + topPadding + 5)

    const unencodedDepths = []
    const alArr = [];
    const refArr = [];
    const seps = [];

    let max = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < depth.length; i+=1){

        const key = i + start;

        if(reference.length > 0){
          alArr.push({
            base: alignment[i],
            key
          })
          refArr.push({
            base: reference[i],
            key
          })
          seps.push({
            base: reference[i] === alignment[i] ? '|' : '',
            key
          });
        }

        let depthVal;
        if(depth[i].match(/[a-z]/i)){
          depthVal = depth[i].charCodeAt(0) - 87; //so that a = 10
        }else{
          depthVal = +depth[i];
        }

        max = max > depthVal ? max : depthVal;

        unencodedDepths.push({
          depth: depthVal,
          key
        });
    }

    const y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .range([height, 0])
      .domain([0, max]);

    //start pos marker
    this.renderMarker([start], this.refs.startPos, topPadding + 7);
    this.renderMarker([max], this.refs.height, height + topPadding - 10);

    if(reference.length > 0){

        this.renderAlignmentComponent(refArr, 10, this.refs.reference, barWidth, leftPadding);
        this.renderAlignmentComponent(alArr, 38, this.refs.alignEl, barWidth, leftPadding);
        this.renderAlignmentComponent(seps, 23, this.refs.sepEl, barWidth, leftPadding);

    }


      //histogram
      d3.select(this.refs.hist).selectAll('rect')
        .attr('height', height)
      .data(unencodedDepths, d => d.key)
        .join(
          enter => enter.append('rect')
            .attr('transform', (d, i) => `translate(${leftPadding + (i * barWidth) - barWidth/2}, 0)`)
            .attr('y', topPadding + 5)
            .attr('x', barWidth/2)
            .attr('height', d => height - y(d.depth))
            .attr('width', barWidth),
          update => update
              .attr('transform', (d, i) => `translate(${leftPadding + (i * barWidth) - barWidth/2}, 0)`)
              .attr('height', d => height - y(d.depth))
              .attr('x', (d, i) => barWidth/2)

      )

      this.renderLabel(reference.length > 0 ? ['Sbject'] : '', this.refs.refNote, 2);
      this.renderLabel(reference.length > 0 ? ['Query'] : '', this.refs.alNote, 30);


  }

  componentDidMount = () => {

    this.componentDidUpdate();
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <StyledSVG  ref="chart">
          <StyledSVG ref="refNote" />
          <StyledSVG ref="alNote" />
          <StyledSVG ref="startPos" />
          <StyledSVG ref="height" />
          <StyledSVG  ref="reference" />
          <StyledSVG  ref="sepEl" />
          <StyledSVG  ref="alignEl" />
          <StyledSVG  ref="hist" />
      </StyledSVG >

    )
  }
}


Alignment.propTypes = {
  reference: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  alignment: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  start: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  depth: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

export default Alignment;
```

The code works well, and re-renders correctly when I change the props to show the next bit of the alignment.

To me, however, it seems excessive with the d3 select calls - but i'm not sure if there's a better way here.

Any suggestions are appreciated!